# Scroll to last item in flatList - Android

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm implementing a Slider using FlatList - React Native,

I have two cases

- press to go to the Next Slide
- press to skip and go to the last item in Slider

so firstly should i know the current index I'm on and based on it
i scroll to the next item,

and to get this index should i use `onMomentumScrollEnd` but the issue is, it's not fired in Android

```
   onMomentumScrollEnd={(ev) => {
          offsetRef.current = ev.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x;
          console.log('ev', ev.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x);
          console.log(' offsetRef.current', offsetRef.current);
    }}


const NextButton = () => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() =>
        flatListRef.current.scrollToOffset({
          animated: true,
          offset: offset.current + width,
        })
      }>
      <Text style={{color: '#fff', fontSize: 16}}>Next</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};


const _renderSkipButton = () => {
    return (
      <AnimatedButton
        onPress={() => {
          // animation();
          // setDoneBtn((prev) => !prev);
          flatListRef.current.scrollToIndex({
            animated: true,
            index: data.length - 1, // Not work!
          });
        }}
        style={[styles.buttonCircle, {transform: [{translateY: skipButton}]}]}>
        <Text>skip</Text>
      </AnimatedButton>
    );
  };




 <Animated.FlatList
        data={data.reverse()}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.title}
        horizontal
        ref={flatListRef}
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        pagingEnabled
        scrollEventThrottle={16}
        contentContainerStyle={{
          paddingBottom: 100,
          flexDirection: 'row-reverse',
        }}
        onScroll={Animated.event(
          [{nativeEvent: {contentOffset: {x: scrollX}}}],
          {useNativeDriver: false},
        )}
        onMomentumScrollEnd={(ev) => {
          const index = Math.round(ev.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x / ITEM_WIDTH);
          const newIndex = I18nManager.isRTL ? data.length - index - 1 : index;
          indexItem.current = newIndex;
          console.log('onMomentumScrollEnd', newIndex);
        }}
        renderItem={....}
       />
```

[Live](https://snack.expo.io/@anastely/onboarding-ex)

Comment: Why are you using offset for prev/next and index for the skip?

Comment: @J.Doe for skip I go the last index its works will (I'm going to index 0) because my app is RTL, for next prev, I'm just trying index and offset but nothing work as expected!

Answer (score 0):

**onMomentumScrollEnd** called when you swipe with your finger, I think you need to manage that manually.

Comment: Not really, the code above work well in iOS, I guess it's a bug, in the next button I scroll to offset bassed on current FlatList offset, but since `onMomentumScrollEnd` not triggered I couldn't get the new offset and that's why the next button not work & stuck in the second Slide :)

Comment: This seems to be a known bug: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21718